# problem while installing gnuhealth client on centos 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, centos7, cairo

when i run  the command ;

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade gnuhealth-client
```

it shows the same error msg everytime

```
gnuhealth@ghealth:~ $ pip3 install --user --upgrade gnuhealth-client
Collecting gnuhealth-client
  Using cached gnuhealth-client-3.6.9.tar.gz (700 kB)
Collecting pycairo
  Using cached pycairo-1.19.1.tar.gz (205 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gnuhealth-client) (2.8.1)
Collecting PyGObject
  Using cached PyGObject-3.36.1.tar.gz (716 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-w04za2un/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel pycairo
       cwd: None
  Complete output (31 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-49.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (803 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting pycairo
    Using cached pycairo-1.19.1.tar.gz (205 kB)
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pycairo, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, pycairo
      Running setup.py install for pycairo: started
      Running setup.py install for pycairo: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ax6ip1o2/pycairo/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ax6ip1o2/pycairo/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-2p1yavr2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-w04za2un/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-w04za2un/overlay/include/python3.6m/pycairo
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ax6ip1o2/pycairo/
      Complete output (15 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cairo
      copying cairo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cairo
      copying cairo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cairo
      copying cairo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cairo
      running build_ext
      Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'cairo' found
      Command '['pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'cairo >= 1.13.1']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ax6ip1o2/pycairo/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ax6ip1o2/pycairo/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-2p1yavr2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-w04za2un/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-w04za2un/overlay/include/python3.6m/pycairo Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-w04za2un/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel pycairo Check the logs for full command output.
```

what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED ANSWER
It's PyGObject that is failing

try

```
sudo yum install gcc gobject-introspection-devel cairo-devel pkg-config python3-devel gtk3 cairo-gobject-devel
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib64/pkgconfig
```

before attempting the pip install

This actually worked for me on Centos7

Comment: ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyGObject which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: I've successfully pip3 installed gnu-health myself on a centos 7 host now.  See updated answer